# Concat works but push doesn't while flattening array

Tags: javascript, recursion

Following code works fine to flatten deeply nested array

```
const arr = [[2, [4, 9]], 6, [5,32]];;
const finalArr = [];

function flattenArr(currArr) {
  for (var el of currArr) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      finalArr.concat(flattenArr(el));
    } else {
      finalArr.push(el);
    }
  }
  return finalArr;
}
flattenArr(arr);
console.log(finalArr); // Output:[2, 4, 9, 6, 5, 32]
```

But if I replace `concat` with `push`, it breaks and gives the following output:

`[2, 4, 9, [circular object Array], [circular object Array], 6, 5, 32, [circular object Array]]`

Can anyone help me understand why? Also, what does `[circular object Array]` mean?

Comment: It means the array contains a reference to itself ("circular"). Some logging and an indentation param to `flattenArr` should clear this up, or "playing computer" w/ a pen and paper. Ultimately: you return `finalArr`, so when you call it recursively you push it onto itself (circular).

Comment: I have no answer, but just an FYI ... `array.flat`

Comment: Here `finalArr.concat(flattenArr(el))` concat is just wasted. Concat returns an array but you are not accepting its returned value. So on recursion, only push is doing all work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to point out that the `concat` in your first code is effectively doing nothing. Concat creates a new array and returns that array, but you're not using the returned array. So if you replace `finalArr.concat(flattenArr(el));` with `flattenArr(el);` your code will still work.

```js
const arr = [[2, [4, 9]], 6, [5,32]];
const finalArr = [];

function flattenArr(currArr) {
  for (var el of currArr) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      flattenArr(el)
    } else {
      finalArr.push(el);
    }
  }
  return finalArr;
}
flattenArr(arr);
console.log(finalArr); // Output:[2, 4, 9, 6, 5, 32]
```

But when you switch it to `.push`, push *does* do something. It's going to insert into the existing `finalArr` array. And the thing it's going to insert is whatever's returned by `flattenArr(el)`, which is `finalArr`. So you're pushing the array into itself, which ends up with circular references (the array contains itself, which contains itself, which contains itself, etc), and that's why some consoles will log it as [circular object Array].

---

The core issue you have is that you only ever use one array for computing the output: the array named `finalArr`, which you define on line 2. That is one way to solve array flattening, as your first code demonstrates. But if you prefer to do it by recursively flattening subarrays, and then combining them with push (or concat), then each time you recurse, you need to make a new array.

A second issue is that when you do the `.push`, you need to pass the individual items of the array as separate arguments, not the entire array as one argument. This can be done with spread syntax (`...`).

For example:

```js
const arr = [[2, [4, 9]], 6, [5,32]];

function flattenArr(currArr) {
  const result = []; // Creating a brand new array
  for (var el of currArr) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      result.push(...flattenArr(el)); // Note that i used spread syntax here
    } else {
      result.push(el);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const finalArr = flattenArr(arr);
console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: *you'll want to push the individual items one at a time* Maybe concat is the right solution here